# Invoke-Expression argument splatting with SqlCmd

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, sqlcmd

Assuming:

```
$args = @()
$args += '-E'
$args += "-S 'SERVER'"
$args += "-d 'DATABASE'"
$args += "-Q 'SELECT GetDate() NOW'"
```

`Invoke-Expression "sqlcmd $($args -join ' ')"` produces:

```
NOW
-----------------------
2015-07-27 16:48:26.387

(1 rows affected)
```

My attempts at 'splatting' fail.

> `Invoke-Expression "sqlcmd" @args` and `Invoke-Expression 'sqlcmd'
>   @args` and `Invoke-Expression sqlcmd @args` produce:
>
> ```
> `Error: 7/27/2015 4:53:00 PM:
> At C:\Users\...\default.ps1:34 char:3 +   Invoke-Expression "sqlcmd" @args +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~ [<<==>>]
> ```
>
> Exception: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts
>   argument '-E'.

`& sqlcmd @args` and `& 'sqlcmd' @args` produce:

```
Sqlcmd: '-S 'SERVER'': Unexpected argument. Enter '-?' for help.
```

What is the correct splatting syntax?

** edit **

Similar pattern (source - [Differential backups using 7-zip and PowerShell](http://zduck.com/2013/differential-backups-using-7zip-and-powershell/)):

```
$args = @()
$args += 'a'
$args += "-tZIP"
$args += 'C:\Users\x\Desktop\archive.zip'
$args += 'C:\Users\x\Desktop\a.txt'

& '7z' @args
```

Results:

```
7-Zip [64] 9.38 beta  Copyright (c) 1999-2014 Igor Pavlov  2015-01-03

Scanning

Updating archive C:\Users\x\Desktop\archive.zip

Compressing  a.txt

Everything is Ok

Kernel  Time =     0.031 =   63%
User    Time =     0.000 =    0%
Process Time =     0.031 =   63%    Virtual  Memory =      9 MB
Global  Time =     0.049 =  100%    Physical Memory =      6 MB
```

What's the difference?

Comment: For arguments with names I believe you should be using a hash table to splat and not an array. Also I would expect splatting to `Invoke-Expression` to expect arguments to `Invoke-Expression` (and hence give you the " A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '-E'" since it doesn't know what that means. That all being said since you need the arguments in the string is the first version not more-or-less correct?

Comment: If you mean `Invoke-Expression "sqlcmd $($args -join ' ')"` as the 'first version', yes it works as expected.  I was hoping for slightly-terser (e.g. `& sqlcmd @args`) expression.

Comment: `& $sqlcmd $($args -join ' ')`? Or maybe even just `& $sqlcmd $args`?

Comment: So far as I know splatting is designed for internal commands, not external commands. PowerShell doesn't interact directly with SqlCmd so far as it's arguments go, it simply provides a string to it, and SqlCmd interprets that string to parse out it's arguments.

Comment: `Invoke-Expression` doesn't take arguments collection as a separate parameter. What you want here is probably `Invoke-Command`.

Comment: Invoke-Command is intended for running commands remotely via PowerShell Remoting, and shouldn't be used for this sort of command parsing. A better option when trying to run an external executable like Sqlcmd is Start-Process. But the answer by John Østergaard Petersen is another good way to get splatting to work.

Answer (score 1):

Splatting works with powershell functions and CmdLets. SqlCmd does not support that.
You could write a wrapper for SqlCmd and get it to work that way. See the following example.

```
function SqlCmdWithSplatting
{
param
(
    [string]$server,
    [string]$database,
    [string]$query
)
sqlcmd -E -S $server -d $database -Q $query
}

# Now call that with splatting

$myargs = @{Server="(localdb)\ProjectsV12";database="John";Query="select * from Table1"}

SqlCmdWithSplatting @myargs

    Id         
-----------
          1
          2
          3
```

Answer (score 0):

**First** : I would avoid to give values to `$args` which is a [Powershell automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) reserved for script parameters.

**Second** : here is the way I use to do it :

```
$scriptblock = {fullpath\sqlcmd -S `"(local)\instance1`" <# comment option -S #>`
                                -U a `
                                -P a `
                                -i `"c:\temp\sql.sql`" }
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock
```

You can then use `$args` variable inside the script block and even start it remotly.

```
$scriptblock = {fullpath\sqlcmd -S `"(local)\instance1`" <# comment option -S #>`
                                -U a `
                                -P a `
                                -i `"$($args[0])`" }
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $scriptBlock -argumentList "c:\temp\sql.sql" -computer "remote1"
```

**Remark** :One line per option allow to comment each param, but be careful not to forget a "`" and no space after them when they are at the end of the line.